# Locale migration …

Tags: localization, migration, content

Any thoughts on the best way (if at all) of bulk-migrating content within a site from one locale to another? We have a large(ish) site and want to streamline into a single locale. This means moving a load of content from one locale to another so appreciate any thoughts on how this might be achieved - if at all!

Comment: Seems like you'd want to just do a search/replace for one locale code in the database and swap to a new one?

Comment: That was my thought but when it gets to Matrix content things get a little more complicated … (duplicate key errors, etc)